# Synchronous Promise Chaining

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, chain

I'm trying to understand promise chaining and I'm under the impression the following code should run synchronously since I chained the 'then' statements. Why does it run asynchronously for the 2nd and 3rd data fetches.

```
console.log("Start Program")
console.log("Start Getting Data 1")

new Promise((succes) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("Got Data 1")
        succes()},3000)
    }
).then(()=>{
    console.log("Start Getting Data 2")
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log("Got Data 2")},3000)
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("Start Getting Data 3")
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log("Got Data 3")},3000)
})

console.log("End Program")
```

Comment: you have to return new promise for each `.then` in your first `.then` return one more promiise

Comment: Your second timeout merely logs something after a certain time, it doesn’t resolve any promise and has no influence on the promise chain.

Comment: there would be less problem if you actually getting data, simply return the result (as it should for normal function)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not returning a Promise from the second. So, basically, after finishing first, the next 2 functions are triggered.

If you want that 3 wait for 2 have to do:

```js
console.log("Start Program")
console.log("Start Getting Data 1")

new Promise((succes) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("Got Data 1")
        succes()},3000)
    }
).then(()=>{   
     console.log("Start Getting Data 2")
 return new Promise((succes) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("Got Data 2")
        succes()},3000)
    }
)
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("Start Getting Data 3")
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log("Got Data 3")},3000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need to return a new promise from the `then()` handler. Otherwise the next `then()` handler will execute immediately after the former.

```
).then(()=>{
    console.log("Start Getting Data 2")
    setTimeout(()=>{console.log("Got Data 2")},3000)
    // no promise is returned, next then handler will execute
    // immediately
}).then(()=>{
```

To simplify the promise creation in combination with `setTimeout` MDN suggest wrapping it at the lowest possible level. Creating a helper function that does nothing other than wrapping the old callback function inside a promise.

> ### [Creating a Promise around an old callback API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#creating_a_promise_around_an_old_callback_api)
>
> A [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) can be created from scratch using its constructor.
> This should be needed only to wrap old APIs.
>
> In an ideal world, all asynchronous functions would already return
> promises. Unfortunately, some APIs still expect success and/or failure
> callbacks to be passed in the old way. The most obvious example is the
> [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function:
>
> ```
> setTimeout(() => saySomething("10 seconds passed"), 10*1000);
> ```
>
> Mixing old-style callbacks and promises is problematic. If
> `saySomething()` fails or contains a programming error, nothing
> catches it. `setTimeout` is to blame for this.
>
> Luckily we can wrap `setTimeout` in a promise. **Best practice is to
> wrap problematic functions at the lowest possible level, and then
> never call them directly again:**
>
> ```
> const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
>
> wait(10*1000).then(() => saySomething("10 seconds")).catch(failureCallback);
> ```
>
> Basically, the promise constructor takes an executor function that
> lets us resolve or reject a promise manually. Since `setTimeout()`
> doesn't really fail, we left out reject in this case.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

console.log("Start Program")
console.log("Start Getting Data 1")

wait(3000)
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 1");
  // By not returning the next `then()` handler will be
  // executed immediately.
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Start Getting Data 2");
  // Return a new promise so the next `then()` handler is
  // not immediately executed.
  return wait(3000);
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 2");
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Start Getting Data 3");
  return wait(3000); // <- return promise so next `then` waits
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 3");
});
```

The above could be condensed by combining some of the `"Got Data"` and `"Start Getting Data"` console logs.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

console.log("Start Program")
console.log("Start Getting Data 1")

wait(3000)
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 1");
  console.log("Start Getting Data 2");
  return wait(3000);
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 2");
  console.log("Start Getting Data 3");
  return wait(3000);
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("Got Data 3");
});
```